# Duty for importing a ring from Slovenia into USA

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, us-citizens, import-taxes

I am a US citizen living abroad in Germany. I have purchased a ring online from Etsy and am traveling back to the US soon to propose to my girlfriend. The ring was paid for in USD (between 2500-3000), originated in Slovenia, and shipped to Germany. I'm assuming I will need to declare and pay duty on this upon arrival, but I'm worried because I don't know how to prove anything I say about the ring. Because I bought it online I have no formal paper work. I read online they need proof of origin of items, but because it's a ring there is no information stamped on it or anything.

The only physical paperwork I have are the documents from the packaging. All those say is that it was a 14k gold ring with the origin and destination. I've also taken screen shots of all the online receipts and conversations I had with the seller.

My main questions are:

1. Does anyone know roughly how much this will cost?
2. Is the information I have enough?
3. If not, what information do I need?

Thank you!

Comment: I've heard of Etsy. It's a well known web site. Doesn't it have an order history that you can print?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold.